# Whether the type of application affects the unit per minute cost?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I know that characteristic and numbers of virtual servers or amount of memory we use or region where we run VM influence cost, but question to a specialist.

Is there a type of application that we run that affects unit per minute cost?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a customer service-related question that should be asked at the Google Cloud site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a customer service-related question that should be asked at the Google Cloud site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While other cloud providers charge for services by the hour, Google charges for all services per second, which can add up to major savings when instances are frequently started and stopped.Pricing is different for apps in the [standard environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/about-the-standard-environment) and the [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible). Apps in both environments may also incur [charges from other Google Cloud products](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#related_products), depending on which products they use in addition to App Engine.

Apps in the standard environment have a **free tier** for App Engine resources. Any use of App Engine resources beyond the free tier incurs charges, To estimate costs for App Engine resources in the standard environment, [use the pricing calculator.](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#tab=app-engine)

App Engine does not provide a free tier in the flexible environment.Apps running in the flexible environment are deployed to virtual machine types that you specify. These virtual machine resources are billed on a per-second basis with a 1 minute minimum usage cost.

Billing for the memory resource includes the memory your app uses plus the memory that the runtime itself needs to run your app. This means your memory usage and costs can be higher than the [maximum memory you request for your app.](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#memory)

Refer to the [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#app-engine-pricing)  for more information about pricing.

Answer (score 0):

Google cloud runs a per minute billing model. For applications the billing is factored on the environment you are using.
There are two: standard environment and app engine flexible environment.  Standard environment billing is cheaper than flexible app environment billing.
These quite depends on the resources you are provisioning.  Also I think legacy apps too could be a factor to what you will be billed